# Multicore in Apache solr 4.3

Tags: ubuntu, search, solr, jetty

I downloaded Apache Solr 4.3.0 from http://lucene.apache.org/solr

I want to have an install with multiple cores with the basic Jetty server. However, I never succeed. If I start the example server, the admin interface will see my new core beside "collection1", but I can't find out the URL where I can reach it. localhost:8983/solr is working, but it records all data into collection1 as if it was some kind of default core.

Wich is more intresting, I also tried to start the server with java -Dsolr.solr.home=multicore -jar start.jar. This starts solr with a pre-defined example dual-core configuration. The admin interface works, but I did not find the URL of my cores, every guess of mine returns with 404...

SO my question is, how to set up a multicore solr using its example configurations, and on wich URL I can reach the cores?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out you should not check if a core is working using the url of host:port/solr/corename. It will give a 404 even if the core works and accepts requests. Try with server:port/solr/corename/select?q=text:somestuff